# Selenium com Chrome Headless falha ao obter URL

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chromium

Em meu script de teste simulo o clique em um botão, que gera e abre um PDF em uma nova aba do Chrome.

```
//Imprime consulta
IWebElement btnGeraPDF = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id"));
btnGeraPDF.Click();
Thread.Sleep(4000);

//Aguarda fechamento da página em branco da geração do PDF
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

var urlAbaAtual = driver.Url;
var urlPaginaGeracaoPDF = ".../PDF.ashx?PdfId"; 

while (urlAbaAtual.Contains(urlPaginaGeracaoPDF))            
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Este trecho funciona corretamente ao rodar o script, **exceto** no modo headless.

Ocorre o erro:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://.....
>   timed out after 60 seconds. -> The request was aborted: The operation
>   has timed out.

A exception é exibida no trecho `driver.Url`.

É o mesmo problema retratado [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754092/selenium-with-headless-chrome-fails-to-get-url-when-switching-tabs), apenas com a diferença de que não utilizo o Specflow.

Já procurei na [lista de comandos do Chromium](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#trace-to-console) mas não encontrei nada que possa resolver este problema.

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo? Atualmente utilizo estes comandos do headless:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArguments("--log-level=2");
options.AddArguments("--lang=pt-br");
```

Comment: Tente usar o `RemoteWebDriver` ao invés de usar o `IWebDriver`.

Comment: @FabioCardoso meu projeto não está estruturado para utilizar Selenium Grid, não posso aplicar `RemoteWebDriver` no momento, tem que ser com `IWebDriver` mesmo. Alguma outra sugestão?